# Inplace Upgrade HyperV Server 2016 to 2019

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2016

So if worse comes to worse, I can just clean install and readd my VMs. I just want to see if there's a way to do this.

My understanding is that Server 2016 can do an inplace upgrade to Server 2019, wherein local settings are saved and the core OS is upgraded.

Based on that, I tried with my HyperV 2016 servers. The setup ran, however, it kicks me out with an error after some time regarding a CD key can't be applied.

I did some searching, and this is an issue with Windows Server if you don't have key applied.

However, 2016 and 2019 HyperV do not have CD keys that I can see, and I can't find any way to resolve this online.

Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: https://4sysops.com/archives/free-hyper-v-server-2019-new-features-and-limitations/  At the very end, the installation fails with this message:

0x80070490 - 0x2000e "The installation failed in the SAFE_OS phase with an error during SET_PRODUCT_KEY operation."

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue... Not just inplace from an existing HYPERV but from any windows server.

I got it working by setting the server to boot from USB and that USB was the hyperv install disk (used rufus with MBR instead of GPT).

Before I skipped boot from that USB and it would always give me that error.

It might not be a general solution but might help someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

In [this MS Tech Community topic](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-server-insiders/microsoft-hyper-v-server-2019-is-live-on-the-microsoft/m-p/735199/highlight/true#M1191) a Microsoft employee explained that upgrading Hyper-V Server is unfortunately not supported:

> Hyper-V Server upgrades aren't officially supported (nor has the validation of upgrades of various configurations of Hyper-V Server been conducted). Point well made that the install experience should handle and communicate this better. I can put upgrades on the potential feature list for future versions, but I do want to be clear that this isn't supported.